# Linking with gfortran: _edata: invalid version 21 (max 4)

Tags: linux, fortran, gfortran, rhel6, cblas

I'm working with RHEL6 systems, but need to port the code using C++11 (and even C++14) features. This forced me to build gcc-8.2 by hand, installed under a private prefix (`/prod/pfe/local`). This created a number of executables under `/prod/pfe/local/bin`: gcc, g++, ld, and gfortran.

I'm now trying to build CBLAS, which uses the above gfortran. Building the library (`cblas_LINUX.a`) works fine, but creating an executable fails with a cryptic errors cited in the title:

`gfortran  -o xscblat1 c_sblat1.o c_sblas1.o ../lib/cblas_LINUX.a

/prod/pfe/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /prod/pfe/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8/../../../../lib64/libgfortran.so: _edata: invalid version 21 (max 4)
/prod/pfe/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /prod/pfe/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8/../../../../lib64/libgfortran.so: error adding symbols: bad value`

Did I configure build gfortran incorrectly? If not, how do I solve this problem -- additional `FFLAGS` or `LDFLAGS` of some kind?

Comment: Can you provide the result of `which gcc g++ gfortran ld` and of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: The message implies that your application links at run time to the wrong version of libgfortran. gfortran -v, ldd and g++ -print-search-dirs also should give clues.  Besides, it seems your version of gfortran should be linking to libgfortran4, and may not do so if this antique libgfortran is searched first.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, [according to the gcc-developers](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87341#c3), this is a known bug triggered by the use of the new linker ([gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_(linker))).

Rebuilding the compiler suit with `--disable-gold` solves the problem.

*Update*: correction -- somehow, disabling gold is not good enough. Going back to the binutils-2.30 is what I ended up doing...